# Opencart contact form: Need sender email id in subject or body of email sent

Tags: php, opencart

Would like to have sender email id in subject of the email or the body of the email which is generated via opencart's default contact page. I have tried editing the `catalog/controller/information/contact.php` file

```
$mail = new Mail();

$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');

$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');

$mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');

$mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');

$mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');

$mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');

$mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             

$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));

$mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);

$mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);

$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

$mail->send();
```

to

```
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name'], $this->request->post['email']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));`
```

the above did not help. Let me know what to try or correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for subject

```
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'),$this->request->post['name']).', Email '.$this->request->post['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Or this for subject

```
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'),'').'From '.$this->request->post['name'].', Email '.$this->request->post['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

or this for body

```
$mail->setHtml(html_entity_decode('Enquiry: '.$this->request->post['enquiry'].'<br/> From: '.$this->request->post['name'].'<br/> Email: '.$this->request->post['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: that threw a error  "Error: E-Mail subject required! in "

Comment: This Php code don't think this would have a issue on opencart version but still I am using 1.5.6.4. The below code worked
`$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'].` `.$this->request->post['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));`

Comment: I tried it for 2.3.0.2, try adding some dummy text first to subject and see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157269/discussion-between-kanted-and-mehravish-temkar).